# Matlab - Extract properties as array from object-array

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop

how do I extract an array of object properties from an object array (where each of the objects within that array has that property?)

Ex.:

```
classdef myClass
    properties
        myProperty = 1
    end
end
```

--

```
myObjectMatrix(1:1000)  = myClass()
myObjectMatrix(100:234).myProperty   % what I thought would work but results in lots of individual results
```

[myObjectMatrix(100:234)..myProperty] works, but only in one dimension. I need to use reshape() if I have more than one dimension to 'fold' my results back.

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically that code would act on each member in turn and return a separate answer, so in the end you only get a 1x1 output.

The solution in that example is to use arrayfun(), such as:

```
myObjectMatrix(1:1000)  = myClass()
output = arrayfun(@(x) x.myProperty,myObjectMatrix(100:234))
```

That would give you a 1x135 array containing the value of each of the myProperty member from each of the elements selected from the class array.

In arrayfun you give a function to perform on each element in the array and then the array to act on. In this case I created an anonymous function which simply accesses myProperty on x - where x will be each object in the array in turn.

---

It is important to note that the above will only work if the property is a single value, not a matrix/array. If it is an array then the output will be nonuniform, and you will have to do:

```
output = arrayfun(@(x) x.myProperty,myObjectMatrix(100:234),'UniformOutput', false)
```

In this case 'output' will be a cell array containing the value of the property of each class.